# Celery asynchronous in django does not work

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to create an asynchronous task using celery, but I am not achieving success.

I have a task that sends emails:

```py
@shared_task()
def send_email_example(email_id):
     ...
```

I call it using the `delay()` method:

```py
class SomeModelExample:
    ...
    
    def example(self):
        ...
        send_email_example.delay(self.id)
```

Locally, I run the celery and can use it. However, in my server, when I use the method that calls the function it takes more than 30 seconds and I receive a status code 502.

I hope that my celery setup is ok, because my periodc tasks works.

#### Solution

Testing it myself I saw that the celery is really ok. The problem was with my tests on the server.

Comment: is there additional code in example function that might take longer than 30 seconds as delay should not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

At this stage I would try:

1. Use decorator without brackets: @shared_task
2. Increase harakiri time to >60 seconds on your server to see if it is a task problem or a server problem.